# Is there a way to see previous screen ouput of executed command in Ubuntu? I tried history so far, only show command list

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, output

I've installed hadoop on my ubuntu virtual box, but I want to take a screen shot of my previous executed command so show my steps. So far the only command I know is history, and it shows all the command I've executed. But is there way to get a screen shot of my success command, like how it looks like when it is executed?

This is my command so far:

```
History
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the unix "screen" command and turn on screen's logging. Screen has a lot of options and takes some getting used to. It will log what your screen shows. Both your commands and the output.

Comment: Thank you sir, do I just type screen in my terminal, how do I get a specific previous screen I want to, like a particular command or date?

Comment: Sir so there is no way to get back to a certain previous screen output, since I forgot to take one screenshot of a certain executed command.

Comment: It is true that you cannot capture a previous screen once it is gone. The screen command is intended to be used before your sequence of commands begin. It can be used to log your input and the corresponding output for later use in documentation or auditing. Instead of trying to do screen captures yourself, screen will do it for you.